# Open a file with Ctrl+Click from path in linux terminal

Tags: terminal, iterm2, gnome-terminal

I've seen this feature when working with iterm2 on a macbook: https://coderwall.com/p/5hp1yg/iterm2-cmd-click-to-open-file-in-vim-in-terminal

Basically iterm2 recognizes file paths and lets you open them with `cmd+click` with your favorite editor. Of course it's not wizardry, it doesn't always work with relative paths, but most times it works.

This was extremely convenient. Now on linux mint, I miss this feature. Have someone managed the same feature?

Comment: Gnome terminal doesn't support this yet but there is also an official feature request regarding this: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/-/issues/7054

Comment: it's only 10 years old :D

Comment: Well, no one's gonna solve this if no one's gonna be aware of it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I need similar functions, so I wrote an extension to implement it, especially for search results of `locate` and `find`. Select the full path file with the mouse (double click or trigle click the mouse most of the time), and a menu pops up. Select the opening method, or ctrl-o to open it directly.

A new version:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4848/open-anywhere/

Comment: ONLY for gnome.

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, I seem not able to use it on cinnamon (mint), even though it uses gnome-terminal. The extension doesn't seem to load properly :/ Probably a slightly different format.

Comment: Regret indeed. But only the Gnome-shell-extension can achieve this effect. Or a old tiny script can manully do it, select any filename, press O and Enter in terminal. The script is here, `https://github.com/eexpress/bin/blob/master/o`